# Issue in moving from swrevealcontroller to new view controller in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a swrevealcontroller on my storyboard.I move to different view controller by passing selecting the view controller name in the table view.Now i am also showing a new table view when i tap on one of the item of tableview in swrevealcontroller.In select of new tableview item i want to show a new view controller which will not be part of the swrevealcontroller.But i am not able to show this.

I have tried this code but it does not show the back button when new view controller is shown.

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *vc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because presentViewController present a viewcontroller as a modal one. Secondly, even if you switch from presentViewController to pushviewcontroller an error will be thrown due to the fact that UINavigationController can not be pushed by another UINavigationController.